# Page loads before data binds to the database

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I have a Telerik RadGrid that contains information on users. I have an add user button on the command item template. It opens a form and the user fills out the fields accordingly. After the user clicks submit, I use javascript to pass the ID through the query string to another page. The problem is, when I submit the data the page loads faster than the data binds to the database. Is there a way to slow the page load down, in order for the data to bind beforehand.

Comment: Events are fired in sequence; there should not be a race condition. Please post your code.

Comment: sounds like you need to debug the code and also add break points to your code .. hopefully you are aware that button clicks generate `PostBacks` which means you probably are lacking some `if(IsPostBack)` checks

Answer (score 0):

You can catch submit event in javascript and trigger it manually after set the value.

example:

```
<form id="target" action="destination.html">
  <input type="text" value="Hello there">
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>

$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  setValue(); 
  this.submit()
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DariuszMusielak/gzfmzkav/

Answer (score 0):

Invoke the postback for the main page after the events (database updates) from the first have taken place. Here is a demo that shows an approach: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/integration/gridandwindow/defaultcs.aspx?product=window

You can use regular browser windows if you like, `window.opener` is the reference to the parent dialog so you can invoke the rebind (e.g., call the rebind() client-side method of the grid).